# How do I get global scope inside define function?

Tags: javascript, scope, requirejs, global-variables, requirejs-define

Can you get global scope while using strict mode and also making sure that you can run on non window environment.

See these examples:

```
define(['other', 'thing'], function() {
    // this === window in desktop environment
    // this === GLOBAL in node environment
});
define(['other', 'thing'], function() {
    "use strict";
    // this === undefined in desktop environment
    // this === GLOBAL in node environment
    // As of my understanding node has to be configured using `node --use_strict`
    // (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031888/any-way-to-force-strict-mode-in-node)
    // But that not the point.
});
```

Is there any way to get the global variable (`window`/`GLOBAL`) inside `define`.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8280137/783743

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var global = Function("return this")();
```

If you don't have access to `Function`, then also try

```
var Function = function(){}.constructor,
    global = Function("return this")();
```

Comment: These will be blocked if we're using  CSP and don't allowing unsafe-eval. For example:  `Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https: 'self'".`

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not help, but I did come up with a way to override the context of requirejs modules using the following code...

```
require.s.contexts._.execCb = function(name, callback, args) {
    return callback.apply(/* your context here */, args);
};
```

Again, not sure if that'll help with `use strict` and all, but who knows... :)

https://gist.github.com/jcreamer898/5685754

Answer (score 0):

What i have come op with so far:

```
(function(root) { // Here root refers to global scope
    define('mything', ['other', 'thing'], function() {

    });
}(this);
```

But then I can't use [`r.js`](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/) to minify my application.

And another could be to check what to use:

```
define(['other', 'thing'], function() {
    var root = typeof GLOBAL != 'undefined' ? GLOBAL : window;
});
```

Yet another way it to define a global file which returns the global:

**global.js:**

```
define(function() {
    return typeof GLOBAL != 'undefined' ? GLOBAL : window;
});
```

**mything.js**

```
define(['global', 'other', 'thing'], function(root) {
    // root === window/GLOBAL
});
```

But I don't like these way because what if some 3. global variable is introduced this will break, or if the user in a browser environment defines `GLOBAL` then that will be returned.

I would like to see if anyone have come up with a smarter way.

Answer (score 0):

What if you stored the window reference on another universally accessible object, such as Object.prototype or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do (it works for browsers, node.js and RingoJS - even in strict mode):

```
if (!global) var global = this;

define(['other', 'thing'], function() {
    // use global
});

define(['other', 'thing'], function() {
    "use strict";
    // use global
});
```

Read the following StackOverflow thread for more details: [Defining an implementation independent version of the global object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8280137/783743)